# Run bash command variable on docker-compose "command"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Issue / Context

I am trying to run a docker container using docker-compose. One of the flags on the "command" requires a date which I want it to be 90 days before today in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I thought of passing this using a bash "command" (`$(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")`). But I am struggling to get the correct format to achieve it.

This works fine if I run the `docker run` command directly, but fails when I try to achieve it via docker-compose.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  gphotos:
    image:  ghcr.io/gilesknap/gphotos-sync:3.1.0
    container_name: gphotos
    restart: "no"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: >-
        /storage
        --progress
        --start-date $(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

*There might be easier containers to replicate, as here I already have some ongoing set up with OAuth, etc.*

2. Command: `docker-compose up` (on Unbuntu Server)

### Expected Behaviour

Container runs command `/storage --progres --start-date 2022-12-20`.

This works fine when doing:

`docker run --name gphotos --rm -p 8080:8080 ghcr.io/gilesknap/gphotos-sync:3.1.0 /storage --progress --start-date $(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")`

### Actual Behaviour

With `--start-date $(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")`: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "gphotos".

With `--start-date "$(date +'%F' --date='3 month ago')"`: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "gphotos".

With `--start-date $$(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")`: gphotos-sync: error: unrecognized arguments: +%F --date=3 month ago).  (Seems to be interpreting the command as multiple parts).

With `--start-date "$$(date +'%F' --date='3 month ago')"`: sort of "works", but passes the literal value `$(date +'%F' --date='3 month ago')` instead of `2022-12-20`, hence the container doesn't know how to interpret it.

With `--start-date "date +'%F' --date='3 month ago'"`: sort of "works", but passes the literal value `"date +'%F' --date='3 month ago'"` instead of `2022-12-20`, hence the container doesn't know how to interpret it.

I also tried passing it to an environment variable first, then using the environment variable on the command attribute. However, there might be ways I haven't tried.

### Question

How should I pass `$(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")` to the command attribute on `docker-compose.yaml` so it passes "2022-12-20" in the command?

I am open to using environment variables, but I am trying to avoid using additional scripts to generate the environments file or docker-compose.yaml if that's possible.

Comment: Just to understand your errors, what is your host running Docker? Is it a Windows?

Comment: I am running this on an Ubuntu Server. Adding that to the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` cannot evaluate the "bash-script", i.e. the part `$(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago")`
Interpolation only works for simple variables.

You have to evaluate that string outside and pass in the value as, e.g. an environment variable:

In your .yml change the command to:

```
    command: >-
        /storage
        --progress
        --start-date $START_DATE
```

and set the environment variable `START_DATE` before calling `docker-compose up`:

```
START_DATE=$(date +"%F" --date="3 month ago") docker-compose up
```